# Pytest Command Line: passing in string to use as host

Tags: python, pytest

So what I am trying to do is write a pytest script that allows me to pass in a string as an argument.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the argument to pass in as a whole string instead of having it be treated as separate characters.  I have tried a bunch of options but this is the closest I have gotten.  I feel like I'm just missing some small logic that will make this actually work.

### conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--host", dest="host", type="string", 
                      action="store", default="john", help="Enter an 
                      endpoint for TransactionDS")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'host' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("host", metafunc.config.getoption('host'))
```

### test_args.py

```
def test_host(host):
global endpoint

endpoint = host
if (endpoint == '90.90.90.90'):
    print(endpoint)
else:
    print(endpoint)
```

### command line

pytest -q --host "Chris" test_args.py -s --html=report.html

### output

```
IP Address from Hello World 1 - 
C
.h
.r
.i
.s
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixture value supposed to be a list of values to iterate through.
So if you use string it will treat each char as a value and run the test the len(host) number of time

So just use

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'host' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("host", [metafunc.config.getoption('host')])

py.test -q --host "Chris" test_args.py -s
Chris
.
1 passed in 0.00 seconds
```

I removed from your command line parameter `html` that is not described in  your `conftest.py`

Comment: Thank you!  Worked out perfectly.  Sorry for the "html" part.  I was running it with the reporting library to export for reporting purposes.  Much appreciated.